# cant fix the "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method" how do i fix this?

Tags: java, javafx

this is my main class

```
package system.test.librarysystem;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Library system") ;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); }

}
```

when i try and run it, it gives me these errors

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method**

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.**

this use to run fine but for some reason wont run anymore got no clue why, how do i fix this?

Comment: "Location is required" means the `FXMLLoader` was given a `null` location, which means that `getResource` returned `null` in this case. See the duplicate for details, including techniques for debugging.

Comment: Note that `ClassLoader#getResource(String)` always interprets the argument as an absolute resource path. In a modular world, it also requires the resource's package to be opened unconditionally. In your case, it would make more sense and likely make things easier if you just used `Class#getResource(String)` instead. That method interprets arguments that start with `/` as absolute, and those that _do not_ start with `/` as relative to the class's package.